# Get the most common values in a column according to another / Convert pandas series of series into a dictionary of list

Tags: python, pandas

Is there an easier way to convert a pandas series of series into a dictionary of lists ignoring the values? Instead of iterating over the series in a for loop?
I want to get the most common values in a dataframe according to a column

```py
df = pd.DataFrame([[1,10],[1,10], [1, 11], [1,11] ,[2,20],[2,21], [3,30], [3,30], [3,31]], columns=['A', 'B'])
common_values = df.groupby(['A'])['B'].value_counts()
common_values = common_values[common_values>1]
```

I want at the end to get

```py
{1: [10,11], 3: [30]}
```

Answer (score 2, accepted):

Pandas solution is possible, but slowier, because many operiations - created DataFrame from `MultiIndex` and aggregate `list`:

```
d = common_values.index.to_frame(index=False).groupby('A')['B'].apply(list).to_dict()
print (d)
{1: [10, 11], 3: [30]}
```

So use [`collections.defaultdict`](https://docs.python.org/3/library/collections.html#collections.defaultdict) for better performance:

```
from collections import defaultdict

d = defaultdict(list)
for a, b in common_values.index:
    d[a].append(b)

d = dict(d)
print (d)
{1: [10, 11], 3: [30]
```